# Does $x^3-e^x+\frac{13}{4}=0$ have an analytical solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I'm a little rusty with my math and have forgotten a lot of techniques for solving equations.  I tried using $\ln$ to get rid of $e^x$ but then I end up with $\ln(x^3+\frac{13}{4})=x$ and I'm stuck.

I was able to approximate the solutions by using a graphing calculator to see that there were in fact two solutions and then applying Newton's method.  However, I was wondering if there was an analytical solution I'm just not seeing.

As a side question (if there is no analytical solution), is there a quick way to determine the number of solutions without resorting to a calculator?

Comment: I doubt there are exact solutions, [Wolfram Alpha give $x=-1.44451$ and $4.62971$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3+-+e%5Ex+%2B+13%2F4+%3D+0)

Comment: For the number of solutions, you can sometimes use calculus tricks, such as with Rolle's theorem in order to find an upper bound on the number of solutions. Here, the fourth derivative of the function is $-e^x<0$. So the third derivative has no extrema (hence at most 1 root), the second derivative has at most one extremum (hence at most 2 roots), the first derivative has at most two extrema (hence at most 3 roots), and so the function itself has at most three extrema (hence at most 4 roots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is algebraic (that is, if $x$ is a solution of a polynomial equation with integer coefficients) and not zero, then there's a theorem that says $e^x$ is not algebraic, so $x$ can't be a solution of your equation. By the same token, if $e^x$ is algebraic and not $1$ then $x$ is not algebraic, so $x$ can't be a solution of your equation. So we've pretty much ruled out as possible solutions the numbers you're most familiar with like $\sqrt2$ and $\log 2$. There are more advanced techniques to show that your equation can't have a solution in closed form in terms of the familiar functions of school mathematics; only numerical methods are available.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the number of solutions without resorting to a calculator, you can sketch the functions $x^3$ and $e^x$, and verify how many times the difference between them is 13/4.